# I am trying to embed some python code in html to provide a gui which shows when a tilt is triggered on a tilt sensor

Tags: javascript, python, html, embedding

This is the code I have for the tilt sensor:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    for button in buttons:
        buttons[button]['state'] = GPIO.input(button)

    for tilt in tilts:
        state = GPIO.input(tilt)
        if state == 1:
            message2 = "Tilt detected on " + tilts[tilt]['name']
        else:
            messsage2 = "No tilt detected on " + tilts[tilt]['name']
        time.sleep(1)

    templateData = {
        'buttons' : buttons,
        'tilts' : tilts
    }

    return render_template('magnet.html', **templateData)
```

And this is how I tried implementing it in the html:

```
<h3 align="center">Alerts</h3>
    {% for tilt in tilts %}
    <h4>{{ tilts[tilt].name }}</h4>
    {% if state == true %}
        <p1>Tilt detected</p1>
    {% else %}
        <p2>No tilt detected</p2>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

The main goal I want to acclomplish is to get this to print that a tilt was either detected or not based on the sensors signal from the raspberry pi.  Some have told me I might need to connect the backend to the frontend through JavaScript but I'm not sure, and am not experienced in JavaScript.